# SWIG generated output missing namespace qualifier

Tags: compiler-errors, namespaces, swig

I have a template array that I'm wrapping with swig for use with Python. I create two instances of the template. The first one's wrapper code is correct, but I'm getting a compile error on the second because of a missing namespace qualifier in the generated code ( see copy_from' below).

I don't know if SWIG is getting confused on the two namespaces api & sim, or whether I'm missing some other qualifier in my declarations. Note 'copy_from()' below is just one example; the same error occurs in other api::array wrapper functions. The SWIG interface (.i) file I'm building from
includes and wraps all the types shown below.

UPDATE: I reviewed my .i file to ensure that all wrapped types are %included in the same order they would be encountered if compiling in C++, i.e.:

```
%include "mat3d.h"
%include "XMVECTOR.h"
%include "api_array.h" // api::array template decl.
%include "api_array_types.h" // array<XMVECTOR> instantiation 
%include "array_types.h" // api::array<mat3d> instantiation
```

UPDATE 2: I added a template alias (see UPDATE 2: added alias in the code):
    template  using array = api::array;
and SWIG now adds the sim namespace, e.g. sim::array< mat3d >. No compile error now, since the alias sim::array maps to api::array - but still don't understand why. Don't like that it's generating two different namespaces referring to the same template class...

```
namespace api { 
    template < typename T > class array : public wrapped<array<typename array_internal_type<T> >, typename array_internal_type<T> >
    {
        ...
        int         copy_from( const array<T>& src ); // member generating an error 

    };
}

class XMVECTOR {...} declared in global namespace

namespace api {
    extern template class array<XMVECTOR>;
    %template(xyzV) array<XMVECTOR>;
}

class mat3d { ... } // declared in global namespace

namespace sim {
    template <typename T> using array = api::array<T>; // UPDATE 2: added template alias
    extern template class api::array<mat3d>;
    %template(matrixV) api::array<mat3d>;
}

// sample SWIG-generated code... this wrapper compiles and executes correctly
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_xyzV_copy_from( PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM( self ), PyObject *args ) {
    PyObject *resultobj = 0;
    api::array< XMVECTOR > *arg1 = (api::array< XMVECTOR > *) 0;
    api::array< XMVECTOR > *arg2 = 0;
    ...
}


// this wrapper fails to compile
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_matrixV_copy_from( PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM( self ), PyObject *args ) {
    PyObject *resultobj = 0;
    api::array< mat3d > *arg1 = (api::array_copy_from mat3d > *) 0;
    array< mat3d > *arg2 = 0; // error: no namespace on array; should be api::array. Applying update #2, this is "fixed" as sim::array< mat3d > 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Template problems are usually issues with order of declarations in the .i file, which you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved by moving the %template directive             outside the sim namespace block to global:

```
        // old: 
        namespace sim { ... 
            %template(matrixV) api::array<mat3d>;
        }   

        // new:
        namespace sim { ... }
        %template(matrixV) api::array<mat3d>;
```

...which now generates the correct namespace (api::)

```
 SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_matrixV_copy_from(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
    PyObject *resultobj = 0;
    api::array< mat3d > *arg1 = (api::array< mat3d > *) 0 ;
    api::array< mat3d > *arg2 = 0 ; // correct api:: namespace added
```

Not sure why SWIG had not identified the member function argument correctly here:

```
  template < typename T > class array 
  {
       copy_from( const array<T>& src ); // arg. 'src' is same type as template class (api::array)
  }
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how SWIG interprets %template if it happens to be placed within a namespace. Anyway I'll assume this issue is resolved for now.